# Is convolution in spherical harmonics equivalent to multiplication in the spatial domain?

Tags: convolution, spherical-harmonics

Spherical harmonic convolution is defined as

$$
( k \star f )^l_m = \sqrt{ \frac{ 4 \pi }{2l+1} } h^l_m f^l_m
$$

(See Eq. (B.13) in Appendix B of Wojciech Jarosz's dissertation "Efficient Monte Carlo Methods for Light Transport in Scattering Media": [PDF](https://cs.dartmouth.edu/~wjarosz/publications/dissertation/).)

I have a function with RGB values for every $(\theta,\phi)$ in the spatial domain.  Call this the "**light function**":

[image: light function]

I project this "light function" to spherical harmonics.

[image: spherical harmonic projected light function]

Now, I want to use this lobe function:

[image: zh "selector" function]

to "select" a portion of the "light function", in the SH domain.

[image: This is what I want to do]

Note that the lobe *is* circularly symmetric.

In the spatial domain, this "selection" could be done by a simple multiplication:  for every $ (\theta,\phi) $ simply multiply.  The result will be "keep anything that lines up with the lobe, and discard the rest."

Multiplication in the spatial domain should be convolution in the frequency domain.

But when I [try to convolve the spherical harmonic "lobe" with the spherical harmonic light function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmzVt.jpg), I am getting a "scaled" or "filtered" copy of the light map, **but not in the way I expect!**  I expect to keep everything along the lobe, and discard the rest, as described above.

Comment: In the equation that you state, what is $k$, $f$ and $h$, respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, convolution in spherical harmonics **is not** multiplication in the spatial domain.  According to "[Lambertian Reectance and Linear Subspaces](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1177153/)" by Basri and Jacobs ([PDF](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7b8d/fc5d6e276f8048bb53b4a5e0611019570f1b.pdf)), convolution in spherical harmonics corresponds with *low pass filtering*.

> Just as the Fourier basis is convenient for examining the
> results of convolutions in the plane, similar tools exist for
> understanding the results of the analog of convolutions on the
> sphere. We now introduce these tools, and use them to show
> that in producing reflectance, ***k acts as a low-pass filter***.

Comment: But isn't low-pass filtering a form of convolution? I don't see how your point follows.

Comment: bobobo's original question is about convolution in the "frequency domain" (i.e., spherical harmonics) which corresponds to point-wise multiplication in the "spatial domain" (i.e., points on the unit sphere).  However, the paper by Basri & Jacobs he cites is for the reverse (i.e., convolution in frequency = point-wise multiplication spatially).  As Rahul correctly notes, saying that convolution acts as a low-pass filter is just an illustrative way of describing the mathematical fact that convolution in the spatial domain is equivalent to multiplication in the frequency domain.

Answer (score 4):

That assumption is only true if one of the harmonics is ZONAL

I.e. every component with m not equal to 0, is 0

so then the convolution is with h being the zonal harmonic

$( k \star f )^l_m = \sqrt{ \frac{ 4 \pi }{2l+1} } h^l_0 f^l_m$

Comment: This is correct. The asker bobobobo cited Appendix B Wojciech Jarosz's dissertation ([PDF](https://cs.dartmouth.edu/~wjarosz/publications/dissertation/)), but he read it incorrectly.  Convolution with spherical harmonics is defined in Eq (B.13), which clearly shows that the kernel must have support only on the harmonics for which $m=0$.

Comment: Ultimately, the reason for this restriction is because, unlike translations on the plane, the rotations on the sphere do not commute (i.e., they form a non-abelian group).  For a bit more intuition on this, see [these slides](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Spring15/17.pdf).

Comment: Actually, commutativity isn't the real issue here.  The deep reason for this restriction is that a full convolution of two arbitrary spherical functions, with arbitrary rotation between them, is a function of that rotation.  3D rotations form a 3D space (e.g. Euler angles).  Spherical functions exist on only a 2D space (e.g. latitude/longtitude).  We can't represent a function on a 3D domain using spherical harmonics on a 2D domain.

Comment: In the equation that you state, what is $k$, $f$ and $h$, respectively?