# Spherical harmonics: sum of three spherical harmonics

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, spherical-harmonics

Starting from this question [How to express multiplication of two spherical harmonics expansions in terms of their coefficients?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419343/how-to-express-multiplication-of-two-spherical-harmonics-expansions-in-terms-of), I wanted to find the formula for the point-wise multiplication of spherical harmonic coefficients back in real space.

Formally, using the usual spherical harmonic expansion:
$$\begin{align}
f(\theta,\phi) &= \sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-l}^l Y_l^m(\theta,\phi) f_l^m \\
f_l^m &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)^*f(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta d\theta d\phi
\end{align}$$
I want to calculate the $h$ in real space in terms of the real space functions $f,g$ when they are related by:
$$
h_l^m=f_l^mg_l^m
$$

I arrived at the point where I need to calculate with $\vec n,\vec n_1,\vec n_2$ unit vectors:
$$
K(n,n_1,n_2) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-l}^l Y_l^m(\vec n)Y_l^m(\vec n_1)^*Y_l^m(\vec n_2)^*
$$
Is there any way to simplify this? By this, I mean is there a formula without the sum allowing to easily look at asymptotics ? Perhaps that there are not, but since there is for "dual" problem using Clebsch Gordon, I have high hopes that a standard formula exists. I'm sure that I am not the first to stumble on this problem, but I lack the keywords.

I naturally thought of the addition theorem:
$$
\sum_{m=-l}^lY_l^m(\vec n_1)Y_l^m(\vec n_2) = \frac{2l+1}{4\pi}P_l(\vec n_1\cdot \vec n_2)
$$
However, it is not directly applicable in this case due to the $m$ dependence in the third factor.

Furthermore, by rotational symmetry, by acting via a rotation $R$:
$$
K(R\vec n,R\vec n_1,R\vec n_2)=K(\vec n,\vec n_1,\vec n_2)
$$
so it is a function of $(\vec n\cdot \vec n_1,\vec n\cdot \vec n_2,\vec n\cdot \vec n_3)$, ie the relative angles, which is not obvious from the series expansion. There is a well defined function taking these 3 arguments rather than the 6 arguments when using $\vec n,\vec n_1,\vec n_2$.

**Question**

Is there a simplification for:
$$
K(\vec n,\vec n_1,\vec n_2) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-l}^l Y_l^m(\vec n)Y_l^m(\vec n_1)^*Y_l^m(\vec n_2)^*
$$

Comment: What is $Y^m_l(\cdot)$ ? The spherical harmonics are a two-argument function.

Comment: $Y_l^m$ can be viewed as a function on the unit sphere. The $n,n_1,n_2$ are normal vectors. I used the same notation as in the wikipedia article on [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics).

Comment: Oh I see. I thought the ns were integers.

Comment: The usual procedure is to use the contraction rule in the aforementioned wikipedia article, which rewrites a product of any two of the three $Y_l^m$ as a sum over single $Y_{l'}^{m'}$. The selection rules of the 3j-symbols mean that this is a finite sum. Then one may for example use addition theorems or again the contraction rule to convert the remaining products to single terms of spherical harmoncis.

Comment: @R.J.Mathar I don’t think that the contraction rule is of much use. It applies for a product of harmonics at same spatial positions but different indices. Here, it is rather the opposite, the postions are different but the indices are the same.

Comment: Since it's all a kind of Fourier trnsform on the spherical surface, wouldn't multiplying the coefficients just be convolution of the functions back in real space over the sphere? (Admittedly, before you ask, it's not immediately clear how this generalization should be defined...)

Comment: @JosBergervoet Yes, actually that’s the motivation of my question: to construct the convolution product on the sphere. I would expect it to be an integral over all the rotations (using the Haar measure), but I wanted to see it formally using this approach.

Comment: @LPZ Yes, since we know that Fourier transform over the group SO(3) actually does work, leading to coefficients of the Wigner d functions (i.e. from 3-variable functions to 3-index coefficients), we might hope that this is just some "projection to a subspace". But I've never heard of such a result. It just might not be the case...